# Got 70 Items in Cart which I can't remove!

Tags: cart, error, delete, shopping

Good Morning to all.

First of all please note that I am not the merchant but a buyer. I do use [shop.funko.com](http://shop.funko.com) to **purchase Pop Vinyl Figures**. This problem has been persistent and I **ended up buying via guest** to temporary be able to buy.

However I want to see my order history but whenever I log in (successfully). Whenever I try getting either into my basket or my order history I keep getting the blank white page with

> There has been an error processing your request Error log record
>   number: 712693230067 (numbers vary this is just one).

It is happening on all browsers and cache is clear.

Thanks for any help.

Clayton :)

Comment: Did you check var/log with that record number

Comment: As I said im a normal buyer not the site owner so I dont have the technical info and login. Any idea from where to search? also I got different numbers.

Comment: You've to contact owner for this, as we need to check this file 712693230067 in report folder for exactly what is error

Comment: ow thought you could tell me what to do. Think its useless contacting them as FUNKO are a big company and wont lose their time with something so small.

Comment: With out server access you can't check and fix also